# Issues with sorting using doubly linked list

Tags: c, sorting, debugging, segmentation-fault

I was trying to implement sorting by following method in C - Accept integers and save them into array. Pass each array value and arrange it in a doubly linked list in an ascending order. I have written the program but I am facing a crash, debugging says its a segmentation fault in display function, however I still haven't been able to make that out. 
Hints would be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node //Doubly linked list to store in ascending order
{
    int info;
    struct node *llink; //Left link
    struct node *rlink; //Right link
};

typedef struct node *NODE; //Define a custom data type for pointer to node(a structure)

/*Accept an integer argument and insert into a doubly linked list at appropriate position to arrange in ascending order*/
void list_sort(NODE head,int item)
{
    NODE cur,prev,temp,prev_to_prev;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Allocate block of memory for a new node to be inserted
    temp->info=item; //Assign the integer to info field of the node
    if(head->rlink==NULL) //head->rlink==NULL when the first node is being inserted
    {
        head->rlink=temp;
        temp->llink=head;
        temp->rlink=head; //Last points to first because of circular representation used here
        return;
    }
        cur=head->rlink;
        while(cur!=head)
        {
            prev=cur->llink;
            if(temp->info<cur->info&&temp->info>=prev->info) //when  prev->info<temp->info<cur->info insert between prev and cur
            {
                prev->rlink=temp;
                temp->llink=prev;
                cur->llink=temp;
                temp->rlink=cur;
                return;
            }
            else if(temp->info>=cur->info && temp->info>prev->info) // when temp->info>cur->info and also > prev->info insert at last
            {
                cur->rlink=temp;
                temp->llink=cur;
                return;
            }
            else if(temp->info<cur->info && temp->info<prev->info) // when temp->info<cur->info and also < prev->info insert before them
            {
                prev_to_prev = prev->llink;
                prev_to_prev->rlink=temp;
                temp->rlink=prev;
                return;
            }
        cur=cur->rlink;
        }
}

void list_disp(NODE head)
{
    NODE cur;
    printf("\nSorted elements are - \n");
    cur=head->rlink;
    while(cur!=head)
    {
        printf("%d\n",cur->info);
        cur=cur->rlink;
    }

}

void main()
{
    int items[10],i;
    NODE head,cur;
    head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->llink=head->rlink=NULL;
    head->info=0;
    printf("Enter 5 items to sort: \n"); //Take only 5 items for now
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d",&items[i]); //Read 5 items
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        list_sort(head,items[i]); //Call function for all 5 items
    list_disp(head); //Display the linked list entry by entry 

}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to step through the code in your debugger, inspecting variables as you go.

Comment: Won't your `head` in `main()` be always unmodified if you don't pass by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential issue is that you are not initializing `rlink` and `llink` in some of the cases.

The other is the fact you're using the simple assignment operator instead of the equivalence:

```
temp->info>=cur->info
```

Comment: Okay, so I worked on it a tad and issue was with uninitialized rlink and llink.

Two more lines sorted it out, program working perfectly now. Thanks!